# how to set the position order of flex items with css

Tags: css, flexbox

```
.container {
display: flex;
}
.item {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

```
<div class='container' >
  <div class='item' style="background:red;" ></div>
  <div class='item' style="background:blue;" ></div>
  <div class='item' style="background:green;" ></div>
</div>
```

So div items are in order - red, blue and then green. How can I set them in order - blue, red and then green by using any flex property in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try the `order` CSS property

```
<div class='container' >
  <div class='item' style="background:red; order: 2" ></div>
  <div class='item' style="background:blue; order: 1" ></div>
  <div class='item' style="background:green; order: 3" ></div>
</div>
```